# Installing shower filter - NPT adaptor for larger intake?

Tags: bathroom, shower, pipe, npt

I am in the process of installing a shower filter, and am encountering a challenge where shower head and water pipe are *not NPT*.

The shower pipe has a slightly larger female "wrapper" (apologies as I lack the correct vocabulary. I am holding said "wrapper" in first pic, below. It attaches to an oversized male connector, which cannot allow me to attach the shower filter, see 2nd pic.

[image]
[image]
Two questions:

- is there another less popular standard than NPT that some showerhead makers are using?
- if so, do adaptors exist that would allow me to connect one to the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first picture, you are looking at a ball-swivel assembly that is **part of** the previous shower head that was attached.

If you take a wrench to the flat spots on the swivel-ball base (clearly seen in your first picture) and unscrew the swivel-ball, that entire assembly will come off and you will be left with the standard 1/2" male NPT shower arm thread. NOTE- place a strap wrench or cushioned plier/wrench on the shower arm to hold it prior to attempting removal.

Comment: Thanks for the insights!